# How do I force jekyll to use a specific version when multiple versions are installed?

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, github-pages, rbenv

I'm in the process of setting up my own Github Pages. I wanted to test the site on local machine before pushing to the remote repo. I followed the instructions from https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll.

As per instructions, I tried `jekyll 3.8.5 new` command, since jekyll-3.8.5 is the version github pages uses (https://pages.github.com/versions/). However, jekyll is not able to find version 3.8.5 in my system.

This is on macOS Catalina, with rbenv installed to manage ruby versions. I have tried manually invoking the jekyll version 3.8.5. That totally works.

Here are some snippets from attempt. `gem list` do show 3.8.5 as available version. But `jekyll 3.8.5 new` command bombed out.

```sh
$ gem list jekyll

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

jekyll (4.0.0, 3.8.6, 3.8.5)

$ which jekyll
/Users/deep/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin/jekyll

$ jekyll 3.8.5 new mygh-site
fatal: 'jekyll 3.8.5' could not be found. You may need to install the jekyll-3.8.5 gem or a related gem to be able to use this subcommand.
```

I was able to explicitly invoke jekyll-3.8.5 from the path where it is installed.

```sh
$ /Users/deep/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/exe/jekyll new mygh-site
```

How do I make use of version 3.8.5 when multiple versions of jekyll are present? Appreciate any help to get past this failure.

Comment: If it works on your local machine it will almost certainly work on Github. The changes between these versions are not that big (unless you use a lot of plugins, then it might cause problems). I would just go for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `which jekyll` command suggests you are not using the versions installed through rbenv (likely the system install instead), for me it's this:

```
$ which jekyll
~/.rbenv/shims/jekyll
```

I'd double check your rbenv install instructions (looks installed but not integrated), you might be missing the `rbenv init` command (https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-rbenv-hooks-into-your-shell)

---

Once you've got that sorted, the convention has underscores either side of the version:

```
$ jekyll _3.8.5_ -v
jekyll 3.8.5

$ jekyll _2.4.0_ -v
jekyll 2.4.0
```

Since you are using rbenv, make sure you run `rbenv rehash` after installing a gem so it'll be accessible.

Comment: Damn, I didn't know the convention of using underscores on either of the version. I switched to the jekyll installed through rbenv. **jekyll _3.8.5_** then worked as expected. Thank you so much.